# how can I program an Armstrong number in Javascript with one For loop, given that the algorithm used is mathematically correct?

Tags: javascript

I have tried to code this problem by converting the looped variables from 100 to 999 to strings, seperate it's digits to numerical values, find the sum of them when cubed, it seems correct when I calculate it on pen and paper, however when I log it it just prints all looped numbers from 100 to 999 , he is my code

```
for (var i=100; i<=999; i++){


    var x = i.toString();

    var z = i

    var a = parseInt(x[0]);
    var b = parseInt(x[1]);
    var c = parseInt(x[2]);

    var y = (a * a * a) + (b * b * b) + (c * c * c);



    if (y = z){console.log ("a happy number is " + x);}



}
```

Comment: What is the problem in your code?

Comment: `if (y = z)` => `if (y == z)`

Comment: and why have z at all?if (y===i)

Comment: @E.Maggini correct, why have the variable `y` or the variable `x`...just use `i`

Comment: he is using x as a way to get to substring although he's code is foo......but there are more flexible efficient ways to do it.

Comment: @e.maggini he is actually wasting a small amount of memory and processing because it is using `x` always to do `i.toString();` instead in the `if (y === i){console.log ("a happy number is " + I.toString();}`

Comment: you actually don't need to call to string in this example console.log('happy number is " + i) would suffice

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle for you [JS FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/1oaaqafx/3/)

```js
for (var i=100; i<=999; i++){

   var myString = i.toString();
   
   var a,b,c;
   

   //this is how I would split string apart
   a =myString.substring(0,1);
   
   b =myString.substring(1,2);
   
   c =myString.substring(2,3);
    

    var y = (a * a * a) + (b * b * b) + (c * c * c);

    //this was your logic error
    if (y === i){console.log ("a happy number is " + i);}
}

console.log('done');
```